# Python error only when I run script on Linux cluster: _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Tags: environment-variables, display, python3, cluster, slurm

My question is related to a python error, but I suspect that it is more a Linux question than a python one. Thus I post it first here.

I am running a python script which does a calculation and then produces a plot and saves it in a PDF file. The script runs through on my local machine (Mac OS), but when I run it on the cluster of my workplace (Linux) it crashes when trying to produce the plot on the PDF with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "<my_python_script>.py", line 496, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__": main()

 File "<my_python_script>.py", line 487, in main
    plot(model, obsdata, popt, pdf_file)

 File "<my_python_script>.py", line 455, in plot
    plt.figure(figsize=(11.69, 8.27))

 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 535, in figure
    **kwargs)

 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 81, in new_figure_manager
    return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)

 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 89, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    window = Tk.Tk()

 File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1880, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)

_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Here I substituted `<my_python_script>` to abbreviate the unimportant path and name of my script.

It may or may not be related to the problem, but I should also mention, that the script is not run manually from the command line, but submitted to a `slurm` queue.

Unfortunately I really don't know enough about Unix/Linux to make this work on the cluster. Since it runs on through on my local machine, I suspect that it must have to do something with the settings on the cluster, and in particular with the settings related to my used. The latter I know because I have colleagues for which the script also runs on the very same cluster.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an error with the python code using a library called “tk”.  That’s a library usually used for showing a GUI so it expects to be able to access your display (xserver or similar).

If you are running your code on a “headless” server then this just won’t work because there’s no monitor and your session can’t talk to an xserver.

It looks like this is a known problem with the matplot library.  See here https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7115/#issuecomment-378288788

Apparently it’s as simple as setting an environment variable to change the matplot backend before you run your python script:

```
export MPLBACKEND=agg
```

Obviously you could set this in python via

```
os.environ["MPLBACKEND"] = "agg"
```

Comment: The lack of a display could also likely be solved using `xvfb` or `xpra/xdummy` where an X server is run without a monitor.

Comment: Works! Perfect! Thanks a lot @Philip Couling !